# how to collect fonts in illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, cs5, font-management

I find manually collecting fonts to be a tedious, detail oriented job, is there a plug in or script or something that has thumbs up to do this tedious job for me?

Comment: What OS are you using? When you say "collecting" fonts, are you talking about archiving or grouping them?

Comment: @lawndartcatcher: He's talking about collecting all the fonts used in a particular project, for example when you need to deliver the project to a printer or another designer.

Comment: Either stop using to many fonts in your work, or "Create Outlines" on all text (which many printers require anyway)

Answer (score 4):

Illustrator doesn't have an analog to InDesign's Package feature, so collecting (packaging) the fonts used in a document has to be done by scripting. There is a [packaging script](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1045887) written for AI CS2 that will work at least as far as CS4 (single art board), which might do the trick. Otherwise, your best bet would be to ask on the [Adobe Illustrator Scripting forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator/illustrator_scripting) if anyone has a script that will do what you want. Scripters being incredibly helpful folks, even if there's no existing script the chances are that someone, or more than one, will write one for you and post it.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that this feature has been added to CS6. Maybe this is the excuse you need to convince your boss, or yourself, to upgrade. I don't work for Adobe, I'm just another geek.

Comment: Welcome to GD Prescott. A very useful answer, thanks for adding it!

Answer (score 1):

Certain font managers like Extensis Suitcase Fusion come with plugins for Illustrator and other design programs that allow you to collect fonts as well as dynamically activate fonts when you load a document that contains fonts you have but aren't permanently active.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted all of my live fonts from Illustrator CS5 into a new document in InDesign CS4, selected "Package" and lo and behold it collected the fonts. The fonts weren't "live" but InDesign collected them anyway. Trial and error, in this case it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Text / Find font / Save List ---> it saves a TXT list with all the fonts used in the document.

Then you search them and copy them into a new folder "youMayNameIt—Fonts" inside your project folder.

This is the best way I found using CS5.

Answer (score 0):

Markzware [FlightCheck](http://markzware.com/products/flightcheck/) will do that for Illustrator, Photoshop and many other file formats. Here is a video of how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxcemY1w-0s It will collect all placed or used fonts, images and art-work. Very handy.

Note - I represent Markzware, the makers of FlightCheck.